# Recommended Samples and other settings to remove fireflies?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

I was rendering this single image and wanted to get the best quality render with proper lighting and least (If possible, no) fireflies. I am currently rendering with these settings.

Filter Glossy 0.5

Refractive Caustics Off

Reflective Caustics On

Clamp Direct 0

Clamp Indirect 3

GPU Nvidia GeForce 840m

Tile Size 64x64

Samples 200

Estimated Time per Frame 30 minutes

Is there any way to remove the fireflies further. If so please do tell me.

Comment: It really depends on the scene. You say you're rendering on your gpu, so you should set your tile size to something around 256. It'll render faster which will let you bump your samples up to reduce fireflies.

Answer (score 0):

A great way to reduce the number of fireflies is to clamp. In the Render panel, under Sampling, you'll see `Clamp Indirect`. This will remove any bright pixels (fireflies). Start with a high value, maybe 1-3. Then work your way down until all the fireflies are gone. Clamping does darken your render, so it's important to use the highest number possible so that you keep as much brightness as possible.

[image]

*32 samples, no clamp*

[image]

*32 samples, .5 clamp*

You can further reduce the noise with more sampling, or, you can use denoising if you are in a dev version.